# How to create a common serialization and deserialization configuration of spring-kafka? What would be the best solution?

Tags: spring-kafka

Example Json serialization and deserialization with spring-boot:

```
@Configuration
class ConsumerKafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun defaultKafkaConsumerFactoryCustomizer() = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactoryCustomizer {
        it.keyDeserializer = StringDeserializer()
        it.valueDeserializer = ByteArrayDeserializer()
    }

    @Bean
    fun messageConvertor(): RecordMessageConverter {
        val converter = StringJsonMessageConverter()
        val typeMapper = DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper()

        typeMapper.typePrecedence = Jackson2JavaTypeMapper.TypePrecedence.TYPE_ID
        typeMapper.addTrustedPackages(ResolverKafkaEvents.PACKAGE_GEN_EVENTS)
        typeMapper.idClassMapping = ResolverKafkaEvents
            .resolveEvents
            .mapValues { Class.forName(it.value) }

        converter.typeMapper = typeMapper

        return converter
    }
}

@Configuration
class ProducerKafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun defaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer() = DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer { factory ->
        factory.keySerializer = StringSerializer()
        factory.valueSerializer = JsonSerializer<Any>().apply {
            configure(
                mutableMapOf(
                    JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS to ResolverKafkaEvents
                        .resolveEvents
                        .asSequence()
                        .joinToString(", ") { "${it.key}:${it.value}" }
                ),
                false,
            )
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun customAsyncProducer(
        kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, Any>
    ) = KafkaJsonProducer(kafkaTemplate)
}
```

I know how to serialize into an byte array and accept, parse it every time in all @KafkaListener. Duplicating the code. Is it possible to make a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; you are already using a `JsonMessageConverter`; by default, the framework will resolve the type from the method signature.

Comment: I want to get something like ProtobufMessageConverter :)

Comment: You would need to write your own converter then; the framework does not provide one.

Comment: Why can't RecordMessageConverter be used in @KafkaListener(contentTypeConverter = ...)? Why does contentTypeConverter implement SmartMessageConverter? Or Can I create bean CompositeMessageConverter with my RecordMessageConverter?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, just adding your custom `RecordConverter` as a `@Bean` is enough for boot to wire it into the container factory. It is not currently overridable on the annotation. The `contentTypeConverter` was added for a different purpose. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1791

Comment: I have the next case: 1 topic have json format, 2 topic have protobuf format. Now, I creating two consumer factory and conteiner. One from two with ```RecordMessageConverter```. Can I have common configuration (generic  - <String, ByteArray>) and use ```@KafkaListener(contentTypeConverter = "beanName")```?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.